# Limit results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table with the following columns:

```
Person(id, name, surname)
```

I want to extract people with the same name but only return 5 rows for each name.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: because I am developing an iPad app using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap, i'm using HTML5 local database. I need to maintain the original order.

Comment: What DMBS? Do you need them in a specific order?

Comment: Something like TOP 5, depending on your vendor.

Comment: extract all data or just name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p1.* FROM Person p1
WHERE p1.id in (
    SELECT TOP 5 p2.id FROM Person p2
    WHERE p2.name = p1.name
)
ORDER BY p1.id
```

Comment: It works but the extracted rows are in alphabetical order. I need to maintain the original order.

Comment: I suppose you could add `ORDER BY p1.id` to maintain "original" order.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct top 5  name from Person
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use partition over.  Example:

```
USE Table1;

with TempXYZ as
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by fname order by fname) as ABC
)
SELECT * from TempXYZ where ABC <=5
```

TempXYZ is merely a temp table used to store the data, ABC is a dummy field that will partition over fname.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, surname 
from Person a 
where id in (
select top 5 b.id from Person b where b.name=a.name
)
```

Comment: this is for SQLServer, change top 5 if using other vendors (rownum, limit, ...)